# Reindexing power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The power series I have is derived from the sequence 
$$x+2x^2+x^3+2x^4+x^5+2x^6$$
And what I have is
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}x^{2n+1}+\sum^\infty_{n=1}2x^{2n+2}$$
seeing that the $n$ starts at different values we need to have them start at the same value. So I used $k=n-1$ then $n=k+1$
and when I reindexed I got

$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}x^{2k+3}+2x^{2k+2}$$
Am I correct or did I misunderstand what I am meant to do when reindexing?

Comment: Better write 



$$x(1+2x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a mistake in 2nd line.
The lower limit of the second sum should be n=0, and then also you don't have to reindex , 
$$ x+2x^2+x^3+2x^4+x^5+2x^6$$ 
So therefore 
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}x^{2n+1}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}2x^{2n+2}
=\sum^\infty_{n=0}( x^{2n+1} + 2x^{2n+2})
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{\frac {1}{2} [1+(-1)^n] }x^n $$

Comment: And if I needed to check the interval of convergence, which test would be best suited for this series?

Comment: The given series is equal to $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{\frac {1}{2} [1+(-1)^n] }x^n $$ ,but here Ratio test isn't working.